# What is a term for a server that is functioning 24/7?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If we have some critical servers that have to be running 7 days a week, 24 hours a day and they can't be down even for one second, what is this particular type of server called in English?

Example sentence:

> Our servers must be flawless; they must be _____.

Does the term *productive* suit?

Comment: @EnglishLearner, edit your question to include a sample sentence about how you want to use the phrase.  For example: `"Our servers must be flawless; they must be _____."`

Comment: In this case I think closing because of no sample sentence is following the 'letter' not the 'spirit' of the rules. The question in its current form seems unambiguous.

Comment: As the suggested sample sentence proposed by @BrockAdams seems  uncontroversial would anyone object if someone other that the OP made the edit?

Comment: @k1eran go ahead. I voted to reopen the question because it is *not* off topic. Only one reopen vote needed.

Comment: What is wrong with "always on"?

Comment: @Spencer: or "uninterruptible"?

Answer (score 95):

Critical services have their own terminology for this that lessens the ability to weasel around phrases like "24/7", "round-the-clock", "Mission critical", etc.

It's [**the "Nines" system**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_availability#Percentage_calculation) and is common in legal contracts for "High availability" services.

Calculate "Nines" by taking the percentage of uptime over total time.  For example, if a server was up for only 9 out of 10 seconds, that's 90% or "One nine".

### "Five nines":

The common ["Five nines"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_nines) is 99.999% which still allows 6 seconds of downtime per week.

To get to less than 1 second per week, you need to guarantee "Six nines" or more -- which is a herculean task in the long term. (Even more-so if you don't use the standard "Unplanned" weasel word.)
For example, [Google and Microsoft typically only promise "3 nines"](https://www.intermedia.net/blog/2014/01/28/99-999-uptime-vs-99-9-uptime-the-difference-two-extra-nines-makes/) (and frequently fail even that), which is a whopping 10 minutes down per week.

Comment: +1. This answer is indeed the terminology used in I.T. in SLAs- service level agreements.

Comment: +1 for the expression that allows to communicate factual and precise information, as compared to marketing promises.

Comment: Hello. As I am a confessed ignoramus where IT is concerned, could you please tell me if the expression *the “Nines” system* and  *five nines* exist worldwide? Is the term "nines" internationally recognized, or is it specific to the US? Should I presume that British IT engineers use the same terminology? Thanks.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, I know that "5 nines" is used by many Engineers and Sales-types in Europe and India too -- at least within the international companies where I first heard the term. ... Few would *say* the phrase: "the Nines system", however.  It's just something we use when formally/legally/technically specifying "zero downtime", etc.

Comment: OK, thanks for replying! I think if it's also used/heard in India then it is probably very helpful to the OP, who may or may not be Indian.

Comment: Might be worth adding something to point out this is usually measured over longer periods than a week - quite typically a year. I've known cases where 5 minutes of downtime happens, but they still maintain the 4 9's status as they've been stable for long periods either side of this downtime.

Comment: "Critical" is the answer. I'd be tempted to upvote this one, if you'd unbold the "Five Nines" part and bold the words "Critical" in the first sentence instead.

Comment: @T.E.D., "Critical" is an imprecise weasel word, seldom appears in SLAs, and, like all the other answers, has no meaning in court.  "Zero downtime" is the phrase that's actually used the most, but it is frequently applied, by sales types, to SLAs that are only 3 nines.

Comment: @SEoF, true, but tangential.  Also, the fine print almost always only specifies "unplanned" downtime.  "Your site was down for a day?  Didn't you see the email about how we were finally replacing our laptops with industrial servers?  That was *planned*."  Also, they get you with rounding.  EG `99.985` is "mathematically the same" as `99.99`.

Comment: @BrockAdams - I'm not disagreeing. However, that is the word that is used for this purpose.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am a British IT engineer, and I use the "n nines" terminology to describe different levels of availability.

Comment: +1 Thanks for teaching me a new term. It's tricky since the OP didn't include a sample sentence, but could you (or someone else) include an example usage, either in the answer or a comment? I'm curious about how these phrases are actually employed, in legalese or in conversation.

Comment: @1006a, countless examples are a Google search away.  For example, see [this page's](https://secure.balkancloud.com/en/solution/exchangepremium/) *title*. ... Actual quote from a meeting, BICR: "QA says we should be good for 6 nines except for the Honestar part."

Comment: Thank you for the quote. "Countless examples" are hard to wade through for the uninitiated; one or two well-chosen *typical* examples are far more helpful.

Comment: This is an (utterly fascinating, I guess) technical addendum. It has no relationship at all to the question on this page.

Comment: Lots of nines is not really Herculean to achieve, it can be done quite easily when you realise it applies to a system, *not* any individual server. A cluster of a hundred servers geographically distributed with no SPOF will not suffer downtime at all if you direct traffic away from a downed machine quickly enough (especially if you do it beforehand for planned downtime).

Answer (score 46):

**[round-the-clock](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/round-the-clock)**

> lasting all day and all night.
>   Examples:
>
> - ‘round-the-clock surveillance’
> - ‘He has hired 500 more workers and this month is adding a third shift for
>     **round-the-clock** production - a first in auto manufacturing history.’
>
> Oxford Dictionaries

Comment: The original title was: `What is another word for 24/7 in English?` I am not an IT expert, I know next to nothing about servers, I would not have answered if the original title corresponded precisely with the body. Please see the first comments/suggestions posted below the OP, and the first answer that was posted too. The OP had plenty of time to clarify, but he chose not to. Perhaps servers can be called `round-the-clock` to the layperson, someone like me. I do not know because this is not my field of expertise.

Comment: [The original title](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/389156/1) was `"what does it call in English?"` (^_^) ... And it was NOT a [single-word-request].

Comment: @BrockAdams yes, I know that *now*,  the situation became clearer when I visited [meta](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10239/is-it-correct-to-change-the-title-of-a-question-that-is-broader-than-the-actual#comment41191_10239) yesterday. Nevertheless, the OP suggested the term `productive`,  and if we were to correct the grammar in the  title it would read: `What is it called in English?` so perhaps he thought a single-word was needed which is why the first editor (Perry) included that tag. Can we both agree that the question has nothing at all to do with `grammar`?

Comment: Agreed, [grammar] does not apply.  Submitted a suggested edit.  If the OP ever comes back will he recognize his post? ;)

Comment: "Full-time" or "full time" used to be perfectly acceptable to mean this.  It's clear and does not rely on use (or misuse) of jargon.  See the Merriam Webster dictionary meaning no 2 and Concise Oxford (1996) p 548.  I recall people using it to mean a service including a computer or online service that had to be on all the time.

Answer (score 17):

If the server cannot be down for even one second, the downtime it experiences must be zero seconds.

In other words, it is a **zero-downtime** server.

The term **zero downtime**
 seems to be widely used in the industry, for example
[here](http://www.iheavy.com/2011/06/23/zero-downtime-what-is-it-and-why-is-it-important/) and [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/availability/311390-133499.pdf).

Comment: Linguistically, I support this answer (+1, hence). However, as an experienced developer (and we're talking the sad kind of experience here), I claim that there's no such thing. Every system **will** go down. Instead of talking about ETF (expected time to failure), we talk about ETR (expected time to restore). But it could be specific for my field. Still, no such think as 100% uptime over a longer period. A-ah!   :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten I agree, anyone who promises a service with absolutely zero downtime is making unrealistic hype. [Here](https://www.fullcontrol.net/ZeroDowntimeGuarantee) is (I think) a more realistic viewpoint, saying what they will do when (inevitably) they fail to achieve the zero-downtime goal. (And even there I see they are talking about a network, not an individual server or even a service.) I think "24/7" (from the question) also is generally not completely accurate; it might be more realistic to ask whether you can achieve 23.9 x 7, 23.99 x 7, or 23.999 x 7 on average.

Answer (score 11):

I would go with *high-availability*.

Most, if not all servers, need some down-time when updates and patches are installed.

Comment: "Highly available" was already mentioned, but this is a different formation of the words that one might use.

Comment: No. High availability normally means redundant. That is, if something fails, there is a backup ready to take over. High availability tends to go with high uptime, but they are different.

Comment: @BenAveling point taken. You are right that, within a system, this would imply redundancy. I still think that 'High availability' can be used in connection to a single server to describe its' likelihood of being available at any time.

Comment: @BenAveling I agree that high availability generally requires redundancy, but I think this is a weakness in the question, not this answer. The question _seems_ to imply that no single server in the installation can ever have any downtime, but frankly, before Gary edited the title the requested term could have been interpreted to apply to the servers collectively rather than individually. The original intent of the question is unclear at this point.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a sensible question. The way to get high-uptime is high availability. They've missed the difference between a service and a server. But this is english.stackexchange, not it.stackexchange.  Probably a better answer would be "bullet proof" or "magical unicorn powered".

Answer (score 7):

> "what is this particular type of server called in English"

I would go with either [continuously available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_availability) or [mission critical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mission_critical). These terms better suit the specific context of a system or set of systems that support or underpin a goal or task. Personally I think the first specifically describes the type of system you are asking about.

Comment: I think mission critical is something different: A redundant server is available 24/7, but isn't mission critical (business is just switched to a different server in case of failure). On the other hand, if your business is only open 9 to 5, your server might only be available 9 to 5, and still be mission critical.

Comment: @nikie Yes -- OP's *title* emphasizes passively being on 24/7, but the actual *question* seems to focus more on 100% availability.  If it's mission critical then it's required to be available whenever people need it... which as you say could be 9-5, but applied to an online asset that's expected to possibly be used 24/7 by people around the world, then being "mission critical" implies 24/7 availability.  It's a good distinction, though -- it's technically OK for a mission critical resource to be unavailable whenever there's absolutely zero chance someone could need it.

Comment: Yes to continuously available, and yes to mission critical.  Continuously available means 24.7. Mission critical systems are often 24x7, but not always. And plenty of 24x7 systems are not mission critical. But OP specified both, so yes and yes.

Comment: @Ben Aveling - I think you are perhaps bring too literal. I suggested misson critical because that could very well describe "critical servers..." which "can't be down even for one second". It would depend on the context really but it general it could be applicable.

Answer (score 7):

*A 100% uptime server*:

***[Uptime](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/uptime)***

> Time during which a piece of equipment (such as a computer) is
>   functioning or able to function

-- Merriam-Webster

Here are some examples of the phrase in use: -

> Uptime is never 100%. A world of factors conspire against 100% uptime,
>   and can potentially disrupt the flow of bits from the server to your
>   browser. But despite the number of factors, most hosting companies are
>   at or above 99.9% uptime.

-- [WP Engine](https://wpengine.com/blog/do-you-have-100-uptime/)

> What we mean when we say 100% uptime is that there will never be any
>   downtime in the time period starting now and extending to infinity.

-- [XARPB](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2012/07/03/is-100-uptime-really-possible/)

Comment: Yes it does Mari-Lou A I happen to know this as I work in IT and am intimately familiar with the technical terms. I'll edit my question to cite references that explain this.

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, it was obsolete.

Answer (score 6):

Usually such computers nodes are a group of machines in such a way that either one of these could be down, the group as a whole keeps running and the intended service is delivered. Such systems are highly available systems.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in your title is `rock solid`.

The answer in your question is `mission critical`.

[The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/rock+solid):

> rock-solid or rock solid
>   adj 
>   2. extremely reliable

[The Free Dictionary](http://encyclopedia.thefreedictionary.com/Mission+critical):

> Mission critical 
>   Mission critical refers to any factor of a system (equipment, process, procedure, software, etc.) whose failure will result in the failure of business operations. That is, it is critical to the organization's 'mission'.

Comment: _mission critical_ is one of a set of related criticalities. A 24/7 server might be _business critical_, when its failure doesn't just threaten the mission/goal of the server but of the whole business. Even more critical are _life critical_ servers, where a loss of functionality could be lethal.

Comment: A company that rents snow skis, for example,  could easily have a mission critical system that only operates a few months out of a year.

Answer (score 0):

If you depend on a continuously running server which must not be down for even one second, the term is *time bomb*.

Sooner or later, it will be down for more than one second.

Machines that cannot be down for any reason for more than a second require special hardware with redundancy for fault tolerance, a special operating system, running in dedicated data center.

Comment: Good advice, wrong venue.

Answer (score -3):

I suppose you could use "Continuous", but I believe the word you're looking for is

interminable

Which means:

endless or apparently endless

Comment: "Interminable" doesn't mean something is *running* or *working* continuously. It means something that seems to never end, like a bad movie, or a really boring lesson.

Comment: `I was working on an interminable coding problem for my high-availability service.`

Literally *in-* +*term*; without a set term or time period.

Comment: You want "uninterruptible".